# change a background color of a 3rd party component without changing it's code

Tags: reactjs

Some answers were submitted but please note that background color has to be changed through props, ***NO css at all.***

---

I've a 3rd party component rendered, how can I change it's background color from the wrapper component without changing the code of MediumButton component?

**3rd party component:**

```
class MediumButton extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <button style={{ width: 100, height: 50 }}>{this.props.text}</button>;
    }
}
```

Wrapper component

```
class BackgroundWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(){ super() }

    render() {
        return <MediumButton text={"Click me!"}></MediumButton>;
    }

    componentDidMount() { 
        
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
    }

    getDOMNode() {
        return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    }
}

BackgroundWrapper.defaultProps = {
    backgroundColor: "green"
};
```

App

```
const App = (props) => <BackgroundWrapper backgroundColor={props.backgroundColor} ></BackgroundWrapper>;
```

Comment: Can you try using  `styled-components`

Comment: not possible I think, somehow the button node can be accessed from life cycle methods of the wrapper component to change the button background color.

Comment: You want to edit styles with a prop, but we aren't allowed to edit the code to add a prop, and you want to change styling, but again without being allowed to use css? I don't think your requirements are possible.

Comment: Try using styled components for BackgroundWrapper and assign css for button from properties. Ref: https://styled-components.com

Comment: hi luke, the requirement is `It should use lifecycle methods so that the MediumButton component has a custom backgroundColor applied to its own DOM node.`, there has to be a code based solution, ref nodes etc? can you access this node, is High order component applicable here?

Comment: guys see yash answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best way to add styling. Also `findDOMNode` is deprecated in `StrictMode` i.e it will be soon removed from the library. But to answer your question:

`findDOMNode` returns the underlying element in this case it is `button`. And we can make use of native properties to update the styling. In this case we want update background style so we can do below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.getDOMNode())
      this.getDOMNode().style.background = this.props.backgroundColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follow:

First, import the custom style:

```js
// import style.css stylesheet
import './style.css'
```

Then, render the component to see how can you select the button that needs to change the background and use that [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) in the style.css

```css
your_selector {
    your_css;
}
```

Comment: the color has to change through props, not css

Answer (score -1):

You can trick it like this:

Create a parent `div` element

```
return <div className={`div-{props.backgroundColor}`}><MediumButton text={"Click me!"}></MediumButton></div>;
```

and then you could define a css for this, e.g.

```
.div-green > button  {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: it has to be through props, not css

Comment: hmmm are these backgrounds pre-defined somehow?

Comment: yes, see this line of coe `BackgroundWrapper.defaultProps`

Comment: app is getting props

Comment: ok see my updated answer. hacky but it should work.

Comment: somehow the requirement is to change the underlying node (not the wrapper), there's a solution using life cycle methods

Comment: don't get it. you said "how can I change it's background color from the wrapper component without changing the code of MediumButton component". this code changes the wrapper component. did i miss sth?

Comment: is there a way to change the style of button from the wrapper component, Ref components, hooking into the node, i'm throwing some ideas here.

Comment: i'm not sure  to be honest. i dont think it is possible. i guess you should have access to the child component, but if you had access you could just change the style.